# How to get info from google map when the user interact with it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I have a web page with google world map that the user can click on any place on it to show longitude, latitude, current UTC time, Current local time, and Timezone based on location?

How and where do I start?

Comment: Question too broad...and out of the scope of the site. I would start at the api homepage https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates) example and programming an onCLickListener to get the coordinates.

You can use [this](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation) API to get the timezone from coordinates.